# C++ parameter pack fails to expand

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, variadic-templates

I'm playing with variadic templates and I can't understand why the following code won't compile (GCC 4.9.2 with std=c++11):

It's just an example, but I need similar kind of use in my code and it fails as well:

```
template<int I>
class Type{};
template<typename ... Tlist>
class A{
    public:
        template<int ...N>
            void a(Type<N> ... plist){

            }
};
template<typename ... Tlist>
class B{
public:
    template<int ... N>
        void b(Type<N> ... plist){
            A<Tlist...> a;
            a.a<N...>(plist ...);
        }
};
```

And the use example:

```
B<int, int, int> b;
b.b<1,7,6>(Type<1>(),Type<7>(),Type<6>());
```

I get the following error:

```
file.cpp: In member function ‘void B<Tlist>::b(Type<N>...)’:
file.cpp:58:9: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘...’ token
    a.a<N...>(plist ...);
         ^
file.cpp:58:24: error: parameter packs not expanded with ‘...’:
    a.a<N...>(plist ...);
                        ^
file.cpp:58:24: note:         ‘N’
```

However the following code compiles fine (I just removed Tlist parameters from both classes and adjusted the code accordingly):

```
template<int I>
class Type{};
class A{
    public:
        template<int ...N>
            void a(Type<N> ... plist){

            }
};
class B{
public:
    template<int ... N>
        void b(Type<N> ... plist){
            A a;
            a.a<N...>(plist ...);
        }
};


B b;
b.b(Type<1>(),Type<7>(),Type<6>());
```

Can anyone give me an explanation?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler has no reason to believe that `a.a` is a template; as such, it is mandated to interpret the `<` as the less-than operator. Write:

```
        a.template a<N...>(plist ...);
          ^^^^^^^^^
```

In your second example, it knows that `a.a` is a template, because the type of `a` there does not depend on a template parameter.

Comment: Oh man, I can't believe it's that simple :-) Thanks A LOT! I'll accept your answer when the timer runs out.